# how to keep check box selection in ListView

Tags: android

I have created a custom ListView..  every element of my ListView constructing from a layout.

My layout will have some TextViews and a ToggleButton. My ListView will have some 50 elemnts and my device screen can show 2 elements at a time.

Now if we select ToggleButton on a Item and scroll down my ListView , the selected item will be out of screen and when I come back to the previous selected item I am observinf that selection for that toggle button is gone.

I know that this is a normal behavior in android that It will construct the elements which is currently displaying.

But I want to keep that value.. Is there any way that we preserve selection. or can I tell ListView to donot construct every time.. memory is a not a issue for my application.

Please let me know if there's any good solution for this.

Comment: Which kind of adapter are you using to populate the `ListView`?

Comment: `BaseAdapter` is an abstract class. I was referring to a concrete implementation, like `ArrayAdapter<T>` or `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the states of the checkbox in a map with the position as the key. So whenever the list reloads after scroll, it loads based on the hashmap state. You should write this logic in the getView()